# Simplifying Expressions in xAct

Tags: xact

I am completely new to [xAct](http://xact.es/) and was wondering if it is possible to tell xAct how to simplify expressions.

Is there, for example, a way (e.g. in form of a supplied rule) to automatically simplify Maxwell equations given as

```
CD[-b][CD[-a][A[b]]] - CD[-b][CD[b][A[-a]]]
```

to

```
CD[-a]@F[a, b]
```

where

`F[a_, b_] := CD[a][A[b]] - CD[b][A[a]]` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try making ansatz like the following.

##### defining the manifold and fields

```
DefManifold[M,dim,IndexRange[a,z]];
DefMetric[-1,metric[-a,-b],CD,SymbolOfCovD->{";","\[Del]"},PrintAs->"g"];
DefTensor[A[-a],M];
DefTensor[F[-a,-b],M,Antisymmetric[{-a,-b}]];
```

##### making ansatz

```
expr[]=CD[-b]@CD[-a]@A[b]-CD[-b]@CD[b]@A[-a]
ruleFToA=MakeRule[{F[a,b],CD[a]@A[b]-CD[b]@A[a]}];
ansatz[1]=MakeContractionAnsatz[CD[a]@F[b,c],{-a},ConstantPrefix->"a"];
ansatz[2]=MakeContractionAnsatz[CD[a]@CD[b]@A[c],{-a},ConstantPrefix->"b"];
ansatz[0]=(ansatz[1]/.ruleFToA)+ansatz[2]
```

[image]

##### comparing the constants

```
SolveConstants[expr[]==ansatz[0]]
ansatz[1]+ansatz[2]/.First@Out[]
```

[image]

now taking $a_1=1$ we get the result that
\begin{equation}
\nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}A^{b} -  \nabla_{b}\nabla^{b}A_{a}
\end{equation}
can be collected into $\nabla_{b}F_{a}{}^{b}$.